# ASP.net forms authentication setting returnURL on a link when user is already logged in

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, returnurl

I have a asp.net website which uses forms authentication. When i provide a link to a secure page on the website in a Microsoft Word document it sets a return URL even when i'm already logged in to the website. This means i am redirected to the login page which then directs me to the unauthorised access page even though i am authorised to see the page.

My **web.config** code:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms protection="All" requireSSL="true" name="BSOAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Login/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/secure/securepage.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

This is the code in the **page load** of my login page to redirect me to the unauthorsied access page:

```
        If Request.IsAuthenticated AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl")) Then
            ' This is an unauthorized, authenticated request...
            Response.Redirect("~/UnauthorisedAccess.aspx")
        End If
```

If i put the same link in an email and i click it appears to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `requireSSL="true"` you force the authenticated cookies to be readable only on secure page, any unsecured page is not pass the authentication.

Add this assertion on your code and before the `IsAuthenticated`  to double check that you are call from secure page.

```
Debug.Assert(HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection
                                                  , "Must be on secure page");
```

Also set the `domain="sitename.com"`, with out the `www`, to force the authendicated cookie to be set from both domain and subdomain.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms domain="sitename.com 
        protection="All" requireSSL="true" name="BSOAuthCookie" 
        loginUrl="~/Login/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/secure/securepage.aspx" 
            cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: The link i'm clicking is to a secure page. All the requests are sent over https as soon as a user logs in. Also in my page load method on the login page i have this block of code which amends http to https. Please see my page load method above.

Comment: Then try the `domain` - and set the Assertion to double check it.

Comment: Thanks Aristos! I have tried what you suggested but it is still doing the same.

Comment: @Azeem then more debug on browser to see what and where is that cookie.